# Problem With Self-Hosted Chrome Web App

Tags: google-chrome-extension

On installtion I am provoked with this error message

> Apps must be served with content type application/x-chrome-extension

My manifest file is as follows

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "itsdaniel0",
  "description": "A quick click-through web app",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "update_url": "http://www.itsdaniel0.com/chrome/app/updates.xml",
  "app": {
    "urls": [
      "*://www.itsdaniel0.com/",
      "*://www.itsdamiel0.com/blog/",
      "*://dl.dropbox.com/"
    ],
    "launch": {
      "web_url": "http://www.itsdaniel0.com/blog/"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "logo.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
  ]
}
```

D/L Link - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17087195/chrome_extensions/itsdaniel0-app.crx

Answer (score 1):

you could tell your users to right click on the link ---> Click 'save as'. The file would be downloaded. Then drag file into chrome. Wala!

Answer (score 0):

Requirements are described in [Hosting](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html) section, you need to tune your web server accordingly to send required headers.

Comment: See, I couldn't understand that documentation, where and how do I place them. My other Chrome **Extensions** (in the same folder) load fine, so why does this differ for a Chrome App?