# Chrome App Not Autoupdating

Tags: xml, google-chrome-extension

I would like to be able to auto update a chrome app I am working on, but it does not work.
In manifest.json:

```
"update_url": "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3889893/update.xml",
"version": "0.2.1.5"
```

and in my xml file

```
<gupdate xmlns="http://www.google.com/update2/response" protocol="2.0">
    <app appid="bfogaennogipjpadaajkmjkpndmodmmh">
        <updatecheck codebase="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3889893/Snake.crx" version="0.2.1.5"/>
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

yet my testing file is still stuck on `0.2.1`, despite hitting `update all` several times. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem With Self-Hosted Chrome Web App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367746/problem-with-self-hosted-chrome-web-app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you directly open the extension download in Chrome there is an error:

> Apps must be served with content type application/x-chrome-extension

https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/hosting.html

Comment: Thank you, I am now hosting on github, although it is still not working. Are there any tools I can use?

Comment: Are you uploading it to the downloads section? It works for me. https://github.com/abraham/omnitweet/downloads

Comment: I tried that (before I was using the raw link), but it still does not appear to be working. How are you hosting the xml file?

Comment: In the root of the repo. http://github.com/abraham/omnitweet/raw/master/updates.xml